# Can we use React Native paper components with Native base?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base, react-native-paper

I am creating expo application for Web, Ios and Android uisng native base as UI component library.
I have Floating label in my design but native base v3 has no floating label input.
Can I use React native paper components inside my app.
Is it a good practice or should I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against utilizing two distinct UI libraries within the same project. Instead, it would be more prudent to select a single library that satisfies the project's requirements. Although no library is infallible, I would make every effort to avoid the use of a second UI library. However, if circumstances necessitate its usage, I would keep its implementation to a bare minimum.